# JavaScript/JQuery banner skipping to last slide on pageload

Tags: jquery, pageload, banner

My javascript/jquery banner jumps to the last slide on page load and then quickly back to the first slide. Is there an easy way to just make it stay on the first slide while the page is loading? I can also post the css I have on the webpage, if that helps more. Please see my script below:

```
var jqb_vCurrent = 0;
var jqb_vTotal = 0;
var jqb_vDuration = 6000;
var jqb_intInterval = 0;
var jqb_vGo = 1;
var jqb_vIsPause = false;
var jqb_tmp = 20;
var jqb_title;
var jqb_imgW = 680;
var jqb_imgH = 200;

jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  jqb_vTotal = $(".jqb_slides").children().size() -1;
  $(".jqb_info").text($(".jqb_slide").attr("title")); 
  jqb_intInterval = setInterval(jqb_fnLoop, jqb_vDuration);

  //Horizontal
  $("#jqb_object").find(".jqb_slide").each(function(i) { 
    jqb_tmp = ((i - 1)*jqb_imgW) - ((jqb_vCurrent -1)*jqb_imgW);
    $(this).animate({"left": jqb_tmp+"px"}, 500);
  });

  $("#btn_pauseplay").click(function() {
    if(jqb_vIsPause){
      jqb_fnChange();
      jqb_vIsPause = false;
      $("#btn_pauseplay").removeClass("jqb_btn_play");
      $("#btn_pauseplay").addClass("jqb_btn_pause");
    } else {
      clearInterval(jqb_intInterval);
      jqb_vIsPause = true;
      $("#btn_pauseplay").removeClass("jqb_btn_pause");
      $("#btn_pauseplay").addClass("jqb_btn_play");
    }
  });

  $("#btn_prev").click(function() {
    jqb_vGo = -1;
    jqb_fnChange();
  });

  $("#btn_next").click(function() {
    jqb_vGo = 1;
    jqb_fnChange();
  });
});

function jqb_fnChange(){
  clearInterval(jqb_intInterval);
  jqb_intInterval = setInterval(jqb_fnLoop, jqb_vDuration);
  jqb_fnLoop();
}

function jqb_fnLoop(){
  if(jqb_vGo == 1){
    jqb_vCurrent == jqb_vTotal ? jqb_vCurrent = 0 : jqb_vCurrent++;
  } else {
    jqb_vCurrent == 0 ? jqb_vCurrent = jqb_vTotal : jqb_vCurrent--;
  }

  $("#jqb_object").find(".jqb_slide").each(function(i) { 
    if(i == jqb_vCurrent){
      jqb_title = $(this).attr("title");
      $(".jqb_info").animate({ opacity: 'hide', "left": "-50px"}, 250,function(){
        $(".jqb_info").text(jqb_title).animate({ opacity: 'show', "left": "0px"}, 500);
      });
    }  
    //Horizontal Scrolling
    jqb_tmp = ((i - 1)*jqb_imgW) - ((jqb_vCurrent -1)*jqb_imgW);
    $(this).animate({"left": jqb_tmp+"px"}, 500);
  });
}
```

Here is my HTML on the actual webpage:

```
<div id="jqb_object">   
  <div class="jqb_slides">
    <div class="jqb_slide" title="Vision System" >
      <a href="<?php changeLink('products/overview.php'); ?>">
        <p id="p1">Flowchart programming, powerful toolset, advanced application solving power.</p>
        <img src="img/xg.jpg" title="" alt=""/>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="jqb_slide" title="Scan Cameras" >
      <a href="<?php changeLink('products/vision/xg8000l/overview.php'); ?>">
        <p id="p2">Choose from our 2K, 4K, and 8K line scan camera for your web or cylindrical part inspection!</p>
        <img src="img/line-scan-camera_lrg.jpg" title="" alt=""/>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="jqb_slide" title="Vision System">
      <a href="<?php changeLink('products/vision/xg8000l/overview.php'); ?>">
        <p id="p3">Features a triple-core processor and multi-camera connectivity including line scan cameras.</p>
        <img src="img/xg-8000.jpg" title="" alt=""/>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="jqb_slide" title="Questions?  Ask the expert." >
      <span>Do you have a question about our vision systems? Click here to contact our experts at Vision Support!<a href="<?php changeLink('products/vision/xg8000l/overview.php'); ?>"></a>.</span>
    </div>   
  </div>

  <div class="jqb_bar"> 
    <div class="jqb_info"></div>    
    <div id="btn_next" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_next"></div>
    <div id="btn_pauseplay" class="jqb_btn  jqb_btn_pause"></div>
    <div id="btn_prev" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_prev"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is my CSS**

```
#jqb_object img{ 
  border: none;
}
#jqb_object a {
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
} 
#jqb_object a:link ,
#jqb_object a:visited ,
#jqb_object a:active {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration:none; 
} 
#jqb_object a:hover {
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#jqb_object { 
  position:relative;
  width:680px; height:200px; 
  overflow:hidden;
}


#jqb_object .jqb_bar{
  position:absolute;
  width:680px; height: 30px;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  background:#000000;
  opacity:0.7;
  filter:alpha(opacity=70);

  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Georgia,serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

#jqb_object .jqb_slide{
  position:absolute;
  width:680px; height:200px; 
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color:#FFF
}


#jqb_object .jqb_info{
  position:absolute;
  padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
  float: left;
}

#jqb_object .jqb_btn{
  width: 15px; height: 14px;
  margin: 10px 5px 2px 2px;
  float: right;
}
#jqb_object .jqb_btn_next{
  background-image:url(../img/btn_next.gif);
}
#jqb_object .jqb_btn_prev{
  background-image:url(../img/btn_prev.gif);
}
#jqb_object .jqb_btn_pause{
  background-image:url(../img/btn_stop.gif);
}
#jqb_object .jqb_btn_play{
  background-image:url(../img/btn_play.gif);
}
#p1{
  position: absolute;
  right: 7.3em;
  width: 270px;
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold; top: 1.2em; font-size: 18.5px; 
  line-height:1.5em; 
  letter-spacing:0.02em;
  text-shadow:1px -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
#p2{
  position: absolute; 
  width: 290px; 
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
  padding: 1px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-size: 18.5px; 
  letter-spacing:0.02em; 
  line-height:1.5em; 
  text-shadow:1px -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
#p3{
  position: absolute;
  right: 2.5em;
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  width: 310px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  top: 1.3em; 
  font-size: 18.5px; 
  line-height:1.5em; 
  letter-spacing:0.02em; 
  text-shadow:1px -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: Where's the Java code in this question? Please, write a title carefully!

Comment: Also, could you show the HTML code? It would be better to help you

Comment: Sorry if I did not properly title my question, I am a designer trying to abandon flash, to my knowledge, this is javascript/jquery code? Please see snippet of html below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what you wanna is implement a Carousel... a slider that moves infinitely around the elements.

You don't need to code it... there's a lot of jquery plugins that are already built and you only need to call a function :D

Here are some direct links and a list of 33 plugins, enjoy it :]

- [JCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) - by [Jan Sorgalla](http://sorgalla.com/)
- [jQuery Carousel](http://thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm)
- [33+ Best jQuery Carousel Plugins](http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=55)

**--- edited ---**

Ok.. let's solve ur problem :]

Your CSS is a bit wrong... in fact, you're trying to build a carousel in a different way... in most cases, you don't animate each element, just their container which is inside some mask..

But, in you case, a think this CSS code can fix it:

```
#jqb_object .jqb_slide:first-child{
  z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Those are awesome! I should have gone with something like that in the first place. I still do want to try and get my code working though. I have spent so much time on it and got it exactly how I want it, except for the annoying skipping to the last slide thing in the beginning. I will for sure go with a plug in in the future, believe me!

Comment: If I remove each, the banner just stays on the last slide and it does not autoplay anymore, and the navigation does not work either. $("#jqb_object").find(".jqb_slide").(function(i) { 
  jqb_tmp = ((i - 1)*jqb_imgW) - ((jqb_vCurrent -1)*jqb_imgW);
  $(this).stop().animate({"left": jqb_tmp+"px"}, 500);

Comment: In my script when the banner reaches the last slide, it does a rewind to the left, back to the first slide. It goes trough each slide when this occurs. I am not sure if this is causing the issue? I could cahge this, but I still want it to autoplay

Comment: Strange... paste your CSS to clarify the align of .jqb_slide elements

Comment: Done, I added my css. Thanks so much, for all your help. I do not have my banner live on the internet, but I based my code off of this example [link](http://www.mclelun.com/labs/#jqbanner) If that helps...

Comment: PS: did you know jsfiddle.net ? Start use it to test code and create examples of what u need... doing this, help you became easier :]

Comment: Yea! Almost there. It stays on the first slide now, but the bottom of the first slide disappears, the <div class="jqb_bar">. All the other bottoms of the slides are there. I will check that site out.

Comment: Ok... here is the thing: when you're add elements to the DOM tree, the last elements stays in front of the other.. so, if you add four elements the 4º will overlap the 3º that will overlap the 2º that will overlap the 1º.. this is why the last is the first which you see before your script runs and adjusts the CSS left of the elements. This is the problems that need to be fixed

Comment: Its working now, had to add z-index: 20; to #jqb_object .jqb_bar{ in my css. Thanks for helping me get there!